# How do I solve form not submiting in django

Tags: python, django

I have created a form without using the form model, but the form wouldn't submit any data and I dont get any error message.

The html file

```
    
    <form action="{% url 'wiki:add_test' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input_form">
            <label class ="label_title" for="entry_title">Title:</label>
            <input class="entry_title" type="text" name="entry_title" placeholder="Title">   
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <div class="input_form">
            <div class="input_label"><label for="entry_content">Content:</label></div>
            <div class="input_field">
                <textarea class="entry_content" name="entry_content" id="" cols="5" rows="2"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="input_form">
            <div class="title"></div>
            <div class="input_button"><input type="button" value="Add Entry"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

The views.py

```
new_entry = ["Item1", "Item 2"]
def test1(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/display_test.html",{
        "lists": new_entry
    })

def add_test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = request.POST
        print(request.POST['entry_title'])
        list_item = form1['entry_title']
        new_entry.append(list_item)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("wiki:test1")) 
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/add.html")
```

The urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = "wiki"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("test1", views.test1, name="test1"),
    path("add_test", views.add_test, name="add_test"),
]
```

I need help to  know where I went wrong

Comment: What is `views.add`? perhaps it was meant to be `views.add_test`? Also noticed this `new_entry.append(list_item)` and you using `new_entry` in another view, I would recommend not doing that, store your data in the database!

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `new_entry` is a global variable

Comment: I don't recommend using a global variable as I said in the previous comment. How would you make it that data stays after reopening server? Also there would be many users accessing the website simultaneously how would you make sure your data is consistent?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I understand, I was just testing to see if the form will work befor I go depender into saving the form data to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is not submitting because you haven't set the submit buttons type to submit in your html.
change

```
<div class="input_button"><input type="button" value="Add Entry"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="input_button"><input type="submit" value="Add Entry"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked after changing to submit